# Creating dictionary (contains a key with multiple values) from a file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a text file contains:

```
A;99
B;70
D;75
A;90
D;100
B;90
B;78
C;77
```

I want my code to return a dictionary that maps each alphabet to the list of all the score of that alphabet, according to the file given.

The output I want:

```
{'A':[99,90], 'B';[70,90,78], 'D':[75,100], 'C':[77]}
```

This is my code, but it does not work like I want

```
d = {}
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = (line.strip()).split(';')
        d[key] = val

print (d)
```

Please help me how to improve the code

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `collections.defaultdict`, when the key isn't present it'll use the `list` constructor to put an empty one, then you can `append` to it

```
d = defaultdict(list)
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(';')
        d[key].append(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = {}
with open("textfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(';')
        val = int(val)
        if key in d:
            d[key].append(val)
        else:
            d[key] = [val]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It provides a default value (here, an empty list) if the key does not exist. If needed, later you can use `dict` to convert it to a regular dictionary (although I usually keep it as is):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('in_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = (line.strip()).split(';')
        d[key] += [int(val)]

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [99, 90], 'B': [70, 90, 78], 'D': [75, 100], 'C': [77]})

print(dict(d))
# {'A': [99, 90], 'B': [70, 90, 78], 'D': [75, 100], 'C': [77]}
```